# Display sum of inputs on page with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have limited experience with jQuery so any help or advice is much appreciated.

I am trying to get a sum of inputs to display as they are added on a page.

I set up a jsfiddle with the intial work: http://jsfiddle.net/5wU3v/

Here's code from the jsfiddle:

```
Shipping: <input type="text" class="input-small fee" name="ship_fee" id="ship-fee">

Other: <input type="text" class="input-small fee" name="other_fee" id="other-fee">

<div>
    $ <span id="total" data-total="<?=$total?>"><p></p></span>
</div>


$('#fee').change(function () {
    var total = $('.total').val();
    $("p").text(total);
});
```

However I can't seem to get even a single input value to display, and consequently I have not added code to figure out the sums yet.

Comment: You probably mean `$('.fee').change` ?

Comment: classes are selected using dot , while ID are selected using # , you are selecting an ID that doesn't Exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//use the class-selector .fe because fee is the class attribute
var $fees = $('.fee').change(function(){
    var total = 0;
    //iterate through all the fee elements and find the total
    $fees.each(function(){
        total += (parseFloat($.trim(this.value)) ||0)
    })
    $( "p" ).text( total.toFixed(2) );
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mM3bu/)

Answer (score 2):

Fee isn't an id, it's a class. Use `.fee` instead. Likewise, total is an id, not a class, so use `#total` instead.