# Jquery sum of inputs from table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to get the sum of an input from a table. Currently I have:

HTML:

```
<tr id='saved1'>
<td><input class='qty'/></td>
<td><input class='price'/></td>
<td><input class='subtotal'/></td>
</tr>
```

Jquery:

```
//COUNT ALL FIELDS
function calculateSum() {
  $("[id^=saved]").each(function() {
    sum = $(this).parent().parent().find('.qty').val() * $(this).parent().parent().find('.price').val();
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.subtotal').val(sum);
    });
  }

// On change
$("input").change(calculateSum);
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display sum of inputs on page with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342169/display-sum-of-inputs-on-page-with-jquery)

Comment: Ur markup never change or it depends on condition??

Comment: depends on condition @Raj

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/77ue7qce/3/

Comment: @lancey check my answer, I accidentally submitted it too early. It contains good advice regardless of whether or not your current solution was fixed already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DOM traversal is wrong. You don't need to go up to the parents, you just need to find the elements in that row.

```
function calculateSum() {
    $("[id^=saved]").each(function() {
        var sum = $(this).find('.qty').val() * $(this).find('.price').val();
        if (!isNaN(sum)) {
            $(this).find('.subtotal').val(sum);
        }
    });
}
```

If the rows are being added dynamically, you need to use event delegation for the binding:

```
$("#tableID").on('change', 'input', calculateSum);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/1j2tanw6/4/)

Comment: This doesnt work neither. To sum it up, the tables are being dynamically added by AJAX and append. It grabs a new row and places it within an existing table. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I've added information about event delegation for dynamically-added elements.

Comment: That worked.... What I realized as well is that it wasnt on dom ready.... I thought that since its a function it doesnt have to be on dom ready. Going to read up on that now! THANKS!!

Comment: The function doesn't have to be in the DOM ready, but the event binding does, since it has to find the table to bind to.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so your code has a variety of problems (I believe the transversal was wrong, and you are multiplying rather than adding, and you aren't checking for not a numbers/NaNs), and I'm going to address as many as I can.

The cascading style of organization was very hard to read. Using variables can be much easier to read and debug. As you can see, I declared multiple variables with one `var` declaration. Use `var`. It makes variables local rather than global, so you can define `sum` somewhere else without messing up your original functions.

You also try adding 2 unchecked inputs together. As you can see I'm using the bitwise operator:

```
qty = grandparent.find('.qty').val() | 0,
```

This returns `0` if `qty` isn't an integer. This is important, otherwise it will assume the inputs are strings, and append one, rather than adding them together.

I would also strongly recommend you avoid tags such as `$("[id^=saved]")`. Selecting by attributes can be very costly/slow. Not something to worry about immediately, but you see how I avoided using that selector below. You generally want to use an id, class, tag or variable as your selector.

```
function calculateSum() {
    var $this = $(this),
        grandparent = $(this).parent().parent(),
        qty = grandparent.find('.qty').val() | 0,
        price = grandparent.find('.price').val() | 0,
        sum = qty + price;
    $('.subtotal').val(sum);
}

// On change
$("input").change(calculateSum);
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v0zy6asx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/fumili/1/edit)

```
function foo(){
    foo.total += $(this).val() - 0;
}
function calcField(selector){
    foo.total = 0;
    $(selector).each(foo)
    $(selector+'total').val(foo.total);
}
function calcFields(){
    var fields = [".qty",".price",".subtotal"];
    for(var i in fields){
        calcField(fields[i]);
    }
}
$('button').on('click',calcFields);
```